# Fixed point problem involving a minimization

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, fixed-point-theorems, lattice-orders, fixed-points

Let $X \subset {\Bbb R}^n$ be a compact and convex set, and let $f : X \times X \to {\Bbb R}$ be a continuous and differentiable scalar field defined by
$$
f(x,x^*)=g(x) + \sum_{i=1}^n x_ih_i(x^*).
$$
Consider the mapping $T : X \to {\Bbb R}$ defined by

$$ T(x^*) := \arg\min_{x \in X} f(x,x^*).$$

Suppose that $g$ is strictly convex so that the minimization problem is always well-defined and has a unique solution.

I am interested in the set of fixed points of $T$, that is the set of $x^*$ such that $T(x^*)=x^*$. Are there sufficient conditions that we can impose on $f$ such that $T$ has a unique fixed point? Is there a good reference for these types of problems?

Comment: How is this related to lattice orders?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo There are some fixed point theorems on lattices. I thought one might be helpful here.

Comment: Yes, $f$ is continuous and differentiable in my setting. In fact it looks like $f(x,x^*)=g(x)+xh(x^*)$ where $g$ is strictly convex.

Comment: Please include such information in the question itself

Answer (score 1):

(Partial Answer):

Consider the setting when $f$ is a separable sum, i.e.,
$$f(x,x^*)=g_1(x)+g_2(x^*),$$
where $g_1$ and $g_2$ are strictly convex functions.
A sufficient condition is $$\textrm{argmin}g_1=\textrm{argmin}g_2.$$
In fact, the fixed-point iteration $x_{n+1}=T(x_n)$ converges in one iteration. Let $x_0\in X$. Then $$x_1=T(x_0)=\textrm{Argmin}_{x\in X}\;g_1(x)+g_2(x_0)=\textrm{Argmin}_{x\in X}\;g_1(x)=\textrm{Argmin}\;g_2.$$ Therefore, $$x_2=T(x_1)\in\textrm{Argmin}_{x\in X}g_1(x)+g_2(x_1)=\textrm{Argmin} g_1=x_1$$
hence $x_1$ is a fixed point. Then, uniqueness of the fixed point follows from the fact that $g_1$ and $g_2$ are strictly convex.